# Using Office Interopt trouble while converting to XPS

Tags: c#, wpf, office-interop

I am building a simple application which is in charge of collecting Office files found in a specific forlder and then convert them to XPS in order to be able to present them easily in a WPF interface control.

For that I am using WOrd,Excell, powwerpoint office interopt assemblied in my project.
Works great so far, it converts but time to time it converts all documents like a charm and test after it converts only one or 2 field and there return the following execption :

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))."

The exception is retunr at the time it try to create the Word.Application object

```
__wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

Here is my method for converting

```
 private static void ConvertFromWord(IDocument Doc)
    {

        __wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        __wordApplication.Visible = false;
        __wordApplication.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;


        //if (__isWordInitialized == false)
        //    InitializeWord();

        Word.Document wordDocument = null;

        object pSourceDocPath = Path.Combine(new Uri(Doc.OriginalPath).LocalPath,Doc.OriginalFile);
        object paramMissing = Type.Missing;


        string pExportFilePath =MyExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Doc.ConvertedFile) ? GetUniqueXpsFile(new Uri(Doc.ConvertedPath).LocalPath) : Doc.ConvertedFile;

        Doc.ConvertedFile = Path.GetFileName(pExportFilePath);

        try
        {
            var pExportFormat = Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS;
            bool pOpenAfterExport = false;
            var pExportOptimizeFor = Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen;
            var pExportRange = Word.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument;
            int pStartPage = 0;
            int pEndPage = 0;
            var pExportItem = Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent;
            var pIncludeDocProps = true;
            var pKeepIRM = true;
            var pCreateBookmarks = Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks;
            var pDocStructureTags = true;
            var pBitmapMissingFonts = true;
            var pUseISO19005_1 = false;
            //var pFixedFormatExtClassPtr=;

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    wordDocument = __wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref pSourceDocPath,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing,
                                                                  ref paramMissing
                        );
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    //return new OfficeToXpsConversionResult(Solatys.Office.Lib.Types.Types.ConversionResult.ErrorUnableToOpenOfficeFile, exc.Message, exc);
                }

                if (wordDocument != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat( 
                                            pExportFilePath,
                                            pExportFormat,
                                            pOpenAfterExport,
                                            pExportOptimizeFor,
                                            pExportRange,
                                            pStartPage,
                                            pEndPage,
                                            pExportItem,
                                            pIncludeDocProps,
                                            pKeepIRM,
                                            pCreateBookmarks,
                                            pDocStructureTags,
                                            pBitmapMissingFonts,
                                            pUseISO19005_1,
                                            ref paramMissing
                                        );
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                       // return new OfficeToXpsConversionResult(Solatys.Office.Lib.Types.Types.ConversionResult.ErrorUnableToExportToXps, "Word", exc);
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    //return new OfficeToXpsConversionResult(Solatys.Office.Lib.Types.Types.ConversionResult.ErrorUnableToOpenOfficeFile);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close and release the Document object.
                if (wordDocument != null)
                {
                    wordDocument.Close(ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,ref paramMissing);
                    wordDocument = null;
                }

                // Quit Word and release the ApplicationClass object.
                if (__wordApplication != null)
                {
                    __wordApplication.Quit(ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
                    __wordApplication = null;
                }

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                __isWordInitialized=false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //return new OfficeToXpsConversionResult(Solatys.Office.Lib.Types.Types.ConversionResult.ErrorUnableToAccessOfficeInterop, "Word", exc);
        }

        Doc.ConvertedFile = pExportFilePath;
        KillWord();
   }
```

Any idea what could be wrong ?
What is strange also is that depending on the amount of document, I can receive a COMException at the same line where it create the application object. I start to be really mad :-(

regards
serge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here are some other questions. In your using at the top of your .cs file, do you have the following..

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

from there where you

```
__wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

change that to be `Application _wordApplication = new Application();`
Where you are passing ref paramMissing -- change that to null pass it just like that null where you are setting the _wordApplication = to null... change it to

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_wordApplication);
```

Com Objects are released differently than managed objects

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused because you are not an Administrator, or do not have administrator priveleges. A well phrased problem is half of the cure, and in this case just make sure tht your account has the administrator priveleges, and is using them.

Could you also paste the code where you are using _wordApplication sounds like a reference issue as well besides the using.. did you add the references via vs2008 or vs2010 make sure that you are copying over the .Dll's if this is something that works on your machine and not the Target Machine.. then it's a definite issue with different versions of Office.Interop running on the machine.. in the project for each of the .dlls that are needed for the Microsoft.Interop stuff... make sure that you are setting copy local = true;

Comment: I am using them with Visual Studio 2010. And there are reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll.

Comment: What is strange also is that depending on the amount of the documents to converts, it can stop after the first document with a CommExecption

Comment: Code added. I am a local admnistrator on my machine and actually I get that error on the machine where I am developping the app. So no deploiement anywhere for the moment, all is local. Also when adding references to my project, I cannot change the CopyLocal propertie, it is set to false and no way to change. On my System I can see Microsoft.Office.Interopt file for version 12 and 14, but actually using 12, can try with 14

Comment: I look it registry the CLSID, it correspond to : "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C". Does it means I need to reference Office Interopt assembly version 14 instead if 12 in my VS project ?

Comment: I have reference version 14 of assembly, seems to remove the exception BUT now i have the follwoing one : "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))"

Comment: Still same error event with library version 14. ANy more idea?

Comment: are you adding this reference as well thru the VS IDE right click on reference--> click add--> once you locate the Microsoft.Office.Interop .dll make sure that in the property window that you are copying the local dll It should work.. I had the same problem 2 weeks ago when the versions of Microsoft Office Changed on our Dev server different from my Local.. also if you can try to Alias the assembly in the using clause at the top.. I did mine as using DOA = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access for my case because of the similar methods in some other assembly.. then in code make the changes to match

Comment: your Alias Assembly.. it's hard to tell what really going on without seeing your actual project.. this is what makes formum site help difficult at times.